# Minimizing distance over finite group action

Tags: reference-request, rt.representation-theory, finite-groups, combinatorial-optimization

Let $G$ be a finite group and $V$ a unitary irreducible rep’n of dimension $N$. Is there a fast (polynomial in $\log|G|$) algorithm to compute $\displaystyle \min_{g \in G}d(x,gy)=\max_{g \in G} Re\langle x,gy\rangle$ for fixed $x,y \in V$?

For a cyclic group acting by rotations on $\mathbb{C}$ this is doable, as well as the standard rep’n of the symmetric group (sort & scale). When $G$ is $\Sigma_n$ acting on a basis of unordered pairs $\{i,j\}$, so $N=\binom{n}{2}$, this is at least as hard as graph isomorphism.

I’m wondering if there is any branch of combinatorial optimization that studies this type of problem, and if it has a name. Generalizing to $G$ a Lie group and arbitrary objective functions, [e.g. $SO(3)$](https://www.cis.upenn.edu/%7Ecjtaylor/PUBLICATIONS/pdfs/TaylorTR94b.pdf), the problem is much more tractable and seems well-studied.

Comment: Perhaps it will be easier to use complex numbers and unitary representations.

Comment: Yes, that makes things a little nicer. Thanks.

Comment: Is $V$ assumed irreducible?  If not then even the cyclic case (which you describe as "doable") seems hard at first blush.

Comment: Yes, let's assume $V$ is irreducible. I wanted to consider the permutation rep'n of $\Sigma_n$ but sorting still works for the standard rep'n.